# Git diff -S to show only lines that match

Tags: git, git-diff

I'm using [this](http://www.brentsowers.com/2012/05/detecting-non-ascii-characters-in-git.html) git hook for preventing commits that include non-ascii characters.

When I find a non-ascii character, I want to print only the line with the character (and if possible the filename and line number too)

```
git --no-pager diff HEAD -S$char -U0
```

The --unified option will show all changes in the file, but I just want to show the lines -S found.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to print only the line with the character (and if possible the filename and line number too)

This is not exactly a `diff` format, but you can easily get what you want by adding `xargs` and `grep` to the mix:

```
%git diff --name-only -S"$char"|xargs grep -n "$char" /dev/null
module/main/src/main/java/Scratchpad.java:33:    public void Reßet() {
```

With GNU grep, you can replace `grep -n "$char" /dev/null` with `grep -Hn "$char"`